# Connection between Determinant and the Quotient Rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives, determinant

For the function $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$, by the Quotient Rule, $\frac{d}{dx} (\frac{f}{g}) = \dfrac{\frac{df}{dx}g-f \frac{dg}{dx}}{g^2}$. We can write the numerator as
$\begin{vmatrix} \frac{df}{dx} & f \\ \frac{dg}{dx} & g \end{vmatrix}$.

I know how to prove the formula by definition of derivative, but I wonder why determinant appears in the numerator? Is there any mathematical relation between derivative of $\frac fg$ and determinant that gives us $\begin{vmatrix} \frac{df}{dx} & f \\ \frac{dg}{dx} & g \end{vmatrix}$ right away?

Comment: I want to say it's just a coincidence. But I can't say for certain, and it would be really cool if someone found an actual connection here.

Comment: I don't have an explanation, but note that the determinant
$$
W(f,g) = \left|\begin{matrix} f & g \\ f' & g'\end{matrix}\right|
$$
called the Wronskian (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian), which detects when $f$ and $g$ are not constant scalar multiples of each other.

Comment: @Deane Thanks! I just asked a similar question about it on mathoverflow site [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396458/connection-between-determinant-and-quotient-rule) and used the term.

Comment: @Arthur: You might be interested in the answers to this question posted on Math Overflow (see Soheil's comment above).